# YUI3 button click event is acting like a submit type instead of a button type

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, yui

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3` with the `Yahoo API version 3`.  I am trying to get my `YUI3 button` to redirect to another page when I click on it, this button is my cancel button.  The cancel button is a plain button type, but it is being treated like a submit button.  It is not redirecting to the correct page, but acting like a submit button and it kicks off my page validation like what the submit button would do.

I thought that it might be with my HTML but I did validate it.  It validated 100% correct.  So I then stripped down the whole page to a bare minimum but the cancel button is still working like a submit button.  Here is my HTML markup:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
     <head>
          <title>Create2</title>
     </head>

     <body class="yui3-skin-sam">

          <h1>Test submit</h1>

          @using (Html.BeginForm())
          {
               <button id="SaveButton" type="submit">Save</button>
               <button id="CancelButton" type="button">Cancel</button>
          }

          <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.6.0pr4/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
          <script>
               YUI().use('button', function (Y) {
                    var saveButton = new Y.Button({
                         srcNode: '#SaveButton'
                    }).render();

                    var cancelButton = new Y.Button({
                         srcNode: '#CancelButton',
                         on: {
                              'click': function (e) {
                                   Y.config.win.location = '/Administration/Department/List';
                              }
                         }
                    }).render();
               });
          </script>

     </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here?  Is this maybe a bug in their API?  I am testing on IE8 and on the latest version of FireFox.

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to mention that if these buttons are not between form tags then the redirect works fine.  If I put them in form tags then the redirect does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Y.Button` widget is removing the `type` attribute from the Cancel button. This makes that button behave like a submit button.

There are many possible paths to make this work. I'll start from simple to complex. The first is to avoid the issue entirely and not use JavaScript at all. Just use a link:

```
<form action="/Administration/Department/Create2" method="post">
    <button class="yui3-button">Save</button>
    <a class="yui3-button" href="/Administration/Department/List">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

After all, all that the Button widget is doing is adding a couple of css classes to each tag and a lot of other stuff that makes more complex widgets possible. As you can see in the [Styling elements with cssbutton](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/button/cssbutton.html) example, even `<a>` tags can look like nice buttons using just the YUI css styles. If you don't have to use JavaScript, better not to use it.

A second option is to avoid the `Y.Button` widget and use the `Y.Plugin.Button` plugin. It's more lightweight in both kb and processing power. And it doesn't touch the tag attributes, so your location code will work.

```
YUI().use('button-plugin', function (Y) {
  Y.all('button').plug(Y.Plugin.Button);
  Y.one('#CancelButton').on('click', function () {
    Y.config.win.location = '/Administration/Department/List';
  });
});
```

And finally you can hack around the behavior of the `Y.Button` widget by preventing the default action of the button:

```
var cancelButton = new Y.Button({
  srcNode: '#CancelButton',
  on: {
  'click': function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      Y.config.win.location = '/Administration/Department/List';
    }
  }
}).render();
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer.  Why do you think it makes the button a submit button?

Comment: Because the default type of a button inside a form is "submit". See the standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-type-BUTTON

Comment: Default or not default, they could have kept the buttons as what they were declared.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a bug. You can file an issue in the YUI issue tracker: http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/newticket/

Answer (score 3):

I would use a link because you are redirecting to another page. Doing it this way you wouldn't need to initialize it with javascript or register the onClick listener.

```html
<button id="SaveButton" type="submit">Save</button>
<a id="CancelButton" href='/Administration/Department/List'>Cancel</a>
```

Look at this link to style your link: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/button/cssbutton.html

Comment: Please elaborate on why you say I need to use a link instad of a button?

Comment: It's a good suggestion.  I have tried the link as well, used my YUI3 initialisation code as above, I just took out the on: part.  When the page loads then it looks like a button.  When I click on it it does the same, submits to the form.  If I take out the YUI initialisation for the link, then it is a submit button with a cancel link next to it.  It doesn't look consistent to me.

Comment: Yes that sets up a button.  Now try adding a click event to it, this is the issue that I am having and getting it to work.  Try it on your side and let me know if it works.Your links points to YUI2.

Comment: Your button initialisation code is totally wrong!  The link also point to YUI2 which has no relation to what I am wanting to achieve.

Comment: Yes I realized that after posting.  Looking through the documentation you should be able to initialize the button as cssbutton, which only adds the style of a button.

Comment: If you see my updates answer (again!) you can see how to style the button. If sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This is a work around yes, but I need to know why it won't work my way?  Is it perhaps a YUI bug.  It is supposed to work like how I did it.