# YUI3 - Onclick event handling for links having same classes

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

Issue: YUI3 - Onclick event handling for links having same classes

We have few links in the page having same class. When I click on one of the links there are some different actions to be taken based on the which link was clicked, For e.g.

```
<a href="?page=1" data="test1" class="sample">One</a>
<a href="?page=2" data="test2" class="sample">two</a>
<a href="?page=3" data="test3" class="sample">three</a>
```

handler code:

```
Y.all('.sample').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.getAttribute("data"));
});
```

when I click any of the links I get the list of all "data" attribute. We only need the data of link clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all` gives you a list of matched elements. You can use `each` to iterate through the list and do stuff for individual node. Refer to their [Node Class API](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/NodeList.html#method_each) for more information.

Here is the code, and [an example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPQsm/).

```js
Y.all('.sample').each(function(node) {
    node.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(node.getAttribute("data"));
    });
});​
```

There is also a FAQ entry for this question in the Event user guide on yuilibrary.com (http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/#nodelist-this).  It's generally preferable to use event delegation.

Comment: @user322896: How well is your YUI skills?  I'm struggling to get my question answered.  You care to advise?

Comment: @BrendanVogt Which question are you struggling with? I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks.  On YUI forum: http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=92&t=10372 and on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701804/yui3-button-click-event-is-acting-like-a-submit-type-instead-of-a-button-type

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `e.target` instead of `this` to access the element being clicked:

```
Y.all('.sample').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(e.target.getAttribute("data"));
});
```

And for even better performance you can use [event delegation](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/#delegation):

```
Y.one('body').delegate('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(this.getAttribute("data"));
}, '.sample');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here event delegation is better solution, agree with @juandopazo

If you do not want to use delegation, you can use Y.all('.sample').each(...) (solution from @user322896) or e.target (solution from @juandopazo), but I usually do it another way:

```
Y.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.getAttribute("data"));
}, '.sample');
```

This is not a delegation syntax (listeners will be attached on links directelly) and there is no NodeList object, so `this` refers to particular link node.
This way is also have preformance advantage comparing to `Y.all('.sample')`, read this: [Why would I use Y.on() or Y.delegate() instead of node.on() and node.delegate()?](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/#y-on-vs-node-on)